# How handel runtime exception that occured when try to make my app compatible for android 3.0?

Tags: android, android-fragments, popup, android-actionbar

I wrote an application that is compatible for android 4.2. But today tried to install in API 11 and get following error

```
  06-24 13:30:22.848: E/AndroidRuntime(645): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-24 13:30:22.848: E/AndroidRuntime(645): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{nebeek.literary.babataher/nebeek.literary.babataher.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-24 13:30:22.848: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1736)
06-24 13:30:22.848: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1752)
06-24 13:30:22.848: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
06-24 13:30:22.848: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:993)
06-24 13:30:22.848: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-24 13:30:22.848: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
06-24 13:30:22.848: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
06-24 13:30:22.848: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-24 13:30:22.848: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
06-24 13:30:22.848: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
06-24 13:30:22.848: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
06-24 13:30:22.848: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-24 13:30:22.848: E/AndroidRuntime(645): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-24 13:30:22.848: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at nebeek.literary.babataher.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
06-24 13:30:22.848: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
06-24 13:30:22.848: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1700)
06-24 13:30:22.848: E/AndroidRuntime(645):  ... 11 more
```

my main activity is as folllow:

```
package nebeek.literary.babataher;

import nebeek.literary.babataher.R;
import nebeek.literary.babataher.setting.HemistichFont;
import nebeek.literary.babataher.setting.IndexFont;
import nebeek.literary.babataher.setting.WebViewActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.TextView;

@SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "ServiceCast" })
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        IndexFragment.OnIndexSelectedListener {

    TextView title;
    private final static String MESSAGE_TO_SETTING = null;
    private static final String HOME_PAGE = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

        View actionBarView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.actionbar,
                null);

        ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarView, params);

        actionBar.setIcon(android.R.color.transparent);
        actionBar.setLogo(android.R.color.transparent);

        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText("دیوان اشعار باباطاهر");

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }

            IndexFragment firstFragment = new IndexFragment();

            firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPoemTypeSelected(String id, String poemType) {
        PoemTypeFragment poemTypeFrag = (PoemTypeFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.type_fragment);

        if (poemTypeFrag != null) {
            title.setText(poemType);
            poemTypeFrag.UpdatePoemTypeView(id, poemType);
        } else {
            String[] value = { id, poemType };
            title.setText(poemType);
            PoemTypeFragment newFragment = new PoemTypeFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putStringArray(PoemTypeFragment.VALUE, value);
            newFragment.setArguments(args);

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();

            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            transaction.commit();
        }

    }

    public void showFontSetting(final View view) {
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, view);
        MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, popup.getMenu());
        popup.show();

        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                String message = "Index";
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.item1:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),
                            IndexFont.class);

                    intent.putExtra(MESSAGE_TO_SETTING, message);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case R.id.item2:
                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(view.getContext(),
                            HemistichFont.class);
                    intent2.putExtra(MESSAGE_TO_SETTING, message);
                    startActivity(intent2);
                    break;
                case R.id.item3:
                    Intent intent3 = new Intent(view.getContext(),
                            WebViewActivity.class);
                    String address = "http://nebeek.com/default/page?view=about";
                    intent3.putExtra(getExtraMessage(), address);
                    startActivity(intent3);
                    break;
                }
                return true;
            }

        });

    }

    public static String getExtraMessage() {
        return HOME_PAGE;
    }

    public void showHomePage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), WebViewActivity.class);
        String address = "http://nebeek.com/documents";
        intent.putExtra(getExtraMessage(), address);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

I checked every things that I used is supported in API 11 too. I don't understand why get this error?